# A possible bug of Mathematica

Tags: series-expansion

There seems to be a bug for Mathematica when evaluating series expansion for expressions containing log functions. For example:

```
tmp1=-(1 - x)^2/(-1 + x^2)^2 - ((1 - x)^2 - ((-1 + x)^2*Log[1 - x])/
 2)/(-1 + x^2)^2;
```

When evaluating

```
Series[tmp1,{x,1,0}]//Normal
```

I get 0, which is obviously incorrect. To see this, we only need to evaluate

```
Series[tmp1//Expand,{x,1,0}]//Normal
```

Has anyone ever met similar problems?

p.s. The version of Mathematica on my PC is "11.0.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)".

Comment: I think the first result is correct since you ask Mathematica to perform a series expansion that is exact up to order `0`, aren't you?

Comment: @ Henrik Schumacher I don't think so, because the first term in "tmp1" is obviously finite up to order 0 in x.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher In fact, adding any term to tmp1 (even a constant), you'll get the same result.

Comment: I see. But `Series[tmp1, {x, 1, 0}]` returns `SeriesData[x, 1, {}, 0, 0, 1] + 
 Log[1 - x] SeriesData[x, 1, {}, 0, 0, 1]` and that tells us that there is a singularity. No matter which constant you add.

Comment: The problem is that `Normal` removes this part. Actually, I am not sure what `Normal` is supposed to do with a power series that is not a power series...

Comment: @ Henrik Schumacher Yes, that's what I call "a bug". Maybe it's not. I'm not sure. Anyway, both the finite term and terms with Log[1-x] are necessary in my calculation.

Comment: On 11.1 I get `1/8 (-4 + Log[1 - x])` for both cases.

Comment: @JohnDoty Ditto on V11.2.  That makes it look like a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: Calling that normalized part `nn`, the evaluation of `Transpose[{tmp1, nn} /. x -> 1. + .01*Exp[2*I*Pi*Range[0, 7]/8]]` gives a strong indication that this is a fixed problem as of at least version 11.2.